# Cannot deploy war file in ElasticBeanstalk-Tomcat7-64bit ami

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tomcat7, war, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a EC2 instance running in Singapore region with AMI: ElasticBeanstalk-Tomcat7-64bit-201208231200 (ami-0cdc9d5e) and I am trying to deploy a war file in it.
Steps I have followed are:

1. copied the war file in /opt/tomcat7/webapps folder
2. changed the owner of war file to be tomcat7
3. changed the permissions of war file to be 777
4. started the tomcat7 server

I have configured the security groups and ensured that the tomcat7 process is running.

However, when I try to browse: http://ec2-54-251-167-184.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/EmailService, I get a clear page. Ideally I was expecting a simple message from the index.jsp file.
I have tested this war file in my local environment running tomcat7 and it works perfectly. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Did you try using Elastic Beanstalk service? It does the deployment for you. It has also integration with eclipse (http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/01/aws-beanstalk-eclipse-integration.html)

Comment: I had tried the Elastic Beanstalk service before this using Eclipse plugin. That failed, so I went about manually deploying it.

Answer (score 0):

Beanstalk service loads a war file from beanstalk application's bucket of S3.
You can upload a war file to the beanstalk application's bucket using [beanstalk console](http://console.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk) or AWS Toolkit for Eclipse.
I think beanstalk console is the easiest way.

If you have not yet created a Beanstalk application environment, please read http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Java.sdlc.html .